# How can i display my other query rows when i got null = 0 values of other returned rows

Tags: mysql, database-design, left-join, coalesce

I have a three tables that i used to left outer join to view all my clinic names including the sum and count for the data that i need, i have here the tables screenshot below:

[image: my tables]

now, i made my query like this:

```
SELECT
tbl_clinics.clinic_name,
COALESCE(COUNT(tbl_check_up.check_up_id),0) AS totalpatient,
COALESCE(SUM(tbl_bill.bill_amt),0) AS totalearn
FROM
tbl_clinics
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_check_up ON tbl_clinics.clinic_id = tbl_check_up.clinic_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_bill ON tbl_bill.bill_id = tbl_check_up.bill_id
WHERE tbl_clinics.user_id = 102
```

The output of my query is this:

[image: myresult]

Problem:
Now, my problem is i want to show my other clinics by showing null to zero values. In my data, i have 3 clinics which has user_id = 102, but why only Clinic 1 shows? . I want something output like this below, where it shows there are no values in tbl_check_up that has a Clinic Id of 2 and 3 same as the bill.

```
+---------------+---------------+------------+
|  Clinic Name  | Total Patient | Total Earn |
+---------------+---------------+------------+
| Clinic 1      |       4       |   800.00   |
+---------------+---------------+------------+
| Clinic 2      |       0       |   0        |
+---------------+---------------+------------+
| Clinic 3      |       0       |   0        |
+---------------+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: Just `group by clinic_name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query (the `COALESCE()` is not necessary for the `COUNT()`):

```
SELECT c.clinic_name,
       COUNT(cu.check_up_id) AS totalpatient,
       COALESCE(SUM(b.bill_amt), 0) AS totalearn
FROM tbl_clinics c LEFT OUTER JOIN
     tbl_check_up cu
     ON c.clinic_id = cu.clinic_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     tbl_bill b
     ON b.bill_id = cu.bill_id
WHERE c.user_id = 102
GROUP BY c.clinic_name;
```

I think you just need the `GROUP BY`.